# While authenticating mongodb using java it is taking more time and throwing mongotimeoutException in case of wrong credential

Tags: java, mongodb

```
MongoClient m = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("182.178.0.29",27017), 
        Arrays.asList(MongoCredential.createCredential("username", "employeedb", "password".toCharArray())));
MongoDatabase md = m.getDatabase("employeedb");
MongoIterable<String> strings = md.listCollectionNames();
MongoCursor<String> iterator = strings.iterator();
```

After authentication i need to show message to end user. But, the exception is comming after 30 seconds in case when the user enters wrong credentials.User needs to wait untill the msg dialog comes. Could you please check why it is taking that much time and is there any other way to authenticate.

MongoDB version: 3.2.14   java driver version: 3.2.1

### Exception:

> com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector

Comment: Are you able to connect to `mongod` from mongo client?

Comment: I suspect it is a network issue. Timeout could be from `182.178.0.29` on `27017` port. You should try to connect to the above ip using telnet from machine which is running java program. Try running `ping` and `telnet` commands

Comment: I am able to connect from putty

Comment: How about telnet? Is 27017 port opened?

Comment: yes port 27017 is opened and i am able to get the data also from mongodb.

Comment: As part of the debugging I suggest connecting to that server from CLI using mongo client and "db address". Then reuse the very same address to initialise MongoClient with com.mongodb.MongoClientURI#MongoClientURI(java.lang.String)

Comment: Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455152/check-mongodb-authentication-with-java-3-0-driver

Answer (score 0):

If you know why your authentication is failing ( you mentioned wrong credentials) , then you can customize the timeout period for failing authentication using [serverSelectionTimeout](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html#serverSelectionTimeout-int-) property so that you can show your users the failed authentication rather quickly.
More explanation can be seen on MongoDB site [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/server-selection-next-generation-mongodb-drivers).

> The serverSelectionTimeoutMS variable gives the amount of time in
>   milliseconds that drivers should allow for server selection before
>   giving up and raising an error. Users can set this higher or lower
>   depending on whether they prefer to be patient or to return an error
>   to users quickly (e.g. a "fail whale" web page). The default is 30
>   seconds, which is enough time for a typical new-primary election to
>   occur during failover.